# How to turn a pump on or off from any of 12 switches

Tags: water, switch

I have a water pump at my home that I want to connect to 12 switches, so that each one of them can turn the water-pump on/off. Can it be done?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd love to hear your use case for this, as well as why you want "alternatives" to 4-way switches.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to want alternatives to 4-way switches. They are not that awesome.  They don't indicate position. They require high voltage in every location... and flowing operating current a long distance and through many connections (46?).  They won't work with high current loads.  With this many control points, other stuff starts to make sense.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the voltage and size of the motor.  Using 4way switches over a long distance is not reasonable with 12VDC motors. How far away are the 12 switches from each other?  Can you give more information on application?  Would it be easier to use a remote control that you can carry anywhere (consider an X-10 module with a remote control)?

Comment: I suspect (reading between the lines) that this is a home in need of a powered potable water system and has 12 locations (baths, laundrys, faucets, etc) that need to be able to turn it on when water is needed and off when not in use.  If this is the case then I suspect a more appropriate description is that you don't actually need to turn it on OR off from any point, you need to be able to turn it ON from any point (the difference is important and impacts the answer to the question) i.e. do you want to allow for multiple users to have it "on" for their duration and not interrupt other users.

Comment: I have no experience with this application, but if OP wants to turn on a pump from any of 12 locations, isn't there some sort of water pressure sensor that will turn on the pump whenever a spigot is opened?

Comment: @JeffMeden - My situation is such - Suppose I am in the kitchen when the overhead tank went empty, I need to turn on the pump to fill it up. But by the time it gets filled up I am in the basement doing something else and I need to turn it off.

Comment: @rtecxs can your tank be operated by a float switch?

Comment: @JS. Yes, a pressure switch is common in caravan applications.

Comment: It may be worth while thinking about something like [EIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instabus)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the first switch in the circuit from the panel would be a three-way switch. The last switch in the circuit before the pump would also be a three-way switch. Then the other 10 switches would all be four-way switches.

[image: Four way switch diagram]

[image: Multiple four way switch wiring]

Comment: So, if suppose i switched on the pump from switch no. 1 then will i be able to switch off the pump from say switch no. 5?

Comment: Yes. It might be educational for you to look at the circuit and figure out why.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to 3 way or 4 way switches?

Comment: @rtecxs 3-way and 4-way switches are cheap, effective, and will do what you're requesting. I'm not sure why an alternative would be necessary, but.. to prevent making things complicated - this would be what you want. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @rtecxs Sure!  Have a bunch of smart switches that route to a home intelligence system, which runs arbitrary code based off of their state, and switches the target device on and off.  All of the functionality, 10 to 100 times the price!

Comment: The only flaw I could see in the 4-way switches is that similar to 3-ways, there's no clear "on" and "off" position on the switch. If you can't hear the pump turning on or off, you don't know if it's already on (use case: you turn on the pump to fill a sink, then in another part of the house I want to flush a toilet, and end up turning the pump off instead of on)

Comment: @AllenGould It'd be easy to run some indicator lights to each switch and all keep with this layout. It's too easy.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you use 4-way switches.  Here is an animation that shows how they work.  You can have as many 4-way switches as you want, in the middle. 
 http://users.wfu.edu/matthews/misc/switches/4WayAnimation.html

Changing the switch causes the pump to change. If it was on, it will be off, or vice versa.  The switch position will not tell the user whether it's on or off.  If you want that, use switches with a "pilot light" feature.

***EDIT: Folding some of my additional comments into my answer.***

There are many "smart switches" on the market that can do a lot of things.  You may be able to adapt these easily.  Some of them even use wireless controls for extra switches, so you don’t have to run wires everywhere.

You could also use pushbuttons (so the pump only runs when a person presses a button).  Either the pushbuttons would have to handle a LOT of current… or they could switch a small DC voltage (12 or 24 volts) which would then operate a relay to power the pump.  The power would come from a small transformer at the pump.   Even better, use a time-delay relay, which will continue running the pump for a set amount of time, so you don’t have to keep holding the button e.g. while the toilet refills.  *Edit: Here's an example of a low-voltage system.  I only show 2 pushbuttons here, add as many as you want. Code-legal versions of these parts are common.* 
[image: Single-pushbutton relay controls]

A more sophisticated method is commonly used in industry. Each location has TWO pushbuttons, an "on" and "off". There is a [latching relay](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/357/105A_755-7090.pdf) at the pump. If someone presses "on" anywhere, the relay switches and stays on.  Push the other, it switches and stays off.  You'd need at least 3 wires, but they can be thin wires. You can’t see the pump status unless you add a pilot light (4th wire).  But you don’t really need to - if you simply press “off”, it’s definitely off. *Edit: Here's an example of a latching relay circuit with 2 push buttons - note the optional "power relay" in case a latching relay isn't strong enough, and also the optional indicator light circuit.* 
[image]
Edit: There's a variant on a latching relay called an impulse sequencing relay.  It only requires one pushbutton, not two, so you don't need the circuit labeled "O".  Every time you press it, it will toggle the relay between on and off.  But it will not indicate on or off, so you might want that indicator light circuit.

Lastly, if you want something really intelligent, you can feed buttons or switches to an Arduino or Raspberry Pi controller and program it to respond as you wish.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to 3 way or 4 way switches?

Comment: Sure, there is  a variety of "smart switches" on the market that can do lots of things.  You could also use pushbuttons (only run when someone presses a button) or use time delay relays so it'll run for some time after the button is released.  If you want something really intelligent, you can feed buttons or switches to an Arduino controller and program it to respond as you wish.

Comment: Or you could wire 12 plain switches in parallel, the pump will run if ANY switch is on, and the switch will indicate.  However if anyone leaves a switch on, you'll have to check 12 places to find it.

Comment: Another method is commonly used in industry. Each location has TWO pushbuttons, an "on" and "off".  There is a latching relay at the pump.  If someone presses "on" anywhere, the relay switches on and latches (stays) on.  If they push "off" anywhere, the relay turns off.   All ”on" buttons are wired in parallel, as are all "off" buttons.  You'd need at least 3 wires, but they can be thin wires. This would not indicate pump status unless you add a pilot light (4th wire).

Comment: @WolfHarper or a single push button at each location which triggers the relay so it switches to the inverse of the current setting. My grandparent's flat hat that for lights (though not 12 ones, just three or four).

Comment: @WolfHarper - Sir, you mentioned something about Raspberry Pi, can you redirect me to any website that has a hint as to how to control an AC devide with a Pi?

Comment: About the Arduino/Pi solution, serious industrial safety cares nothing for software unless it's at least double-redundant and has been thoroughly tested and certified to be 100% reliable in not getting stuck in an unsafe state.  A few software controllers exist that meet that criteria, but Arduino's and RPi's are not among them.  For home application where you're probably not going to be sued by OSHA (or the equivalent gov't agency in your country), you might get away without a guaranteed way of stopping quickly if the software malfunctions, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @rtecxs: Here's one way: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41186/39980  Make sure that the "5V relay" has good enough contact ratings to run the pump directly, or use its contacts to run a bigger relay that in turn runs the pump.  Remember my note about double contacts in series to make sure it stops.  There seem to be several ways to control the GPIO, the most attractive to me being the Linux filesystem: http://luketopia.net/2013/07/28/raspberry-pi-gpio-via-the-shell/  It doesn't matter what language you use as long as you can read and write "files".

Comment: Paulo, could be an impulse sequencing relay, or a 3-way switch in push-on/push-off format.  With any toggle, it's hard to tell if the thing's status is on or off. That can matter for anything you can't directly observe.

Comment: As @AaronD says: If you're writing home automation software/hardware, a failure mode analysis is a good idea.  It doesn't matter too much if you leave a lamp on in a room, but if the software crashes and the pump overfills your tank you have an expensive problem (one which may be eliminated with an additional float switch in this case).  This is in addition to any regulations etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's the general concept, where you use automation, you have to corral it in mechanically so it can't go too far wrong.  You want it reporting an error if it hits an unexpected limit, so you can fix the code.  Although personally I think code gets too complex to be practicably made bug-free pretty quickly.

Answer (score 8):

This is commonly used in industrial controls:

[image: schematic]

I've drawn it as a ladder diagram because I think it's easier to see the individual circuits and the interactions between them.  You can translate from that to the actual wiring.

I'm using a second relay contact to power the load so that the control circuit only has to handle the relay, which is almost nothing in most cases.  You can also add a light in each panel as Wolf mentioned, wired in parallel with the load or with the relay; which one is up to you, but consider how it might fail.

For safety:

- All start buttons should be recessed and all stop buttons protruding.  This allows someone to swat the panel in a panic stop situation but requires them to intentionally start it.
- All stop buttons must interrupt power.  This makes the pump stop immediately if a wire comes loose instead of being impossible to stop from that location.  You really don't want to discover that in an emergency.
- You might also consider using double contacts for the stop buttons and for the relay contact that powers the load.  Make sure that if one decides to weld itself, the other can still operate, and wire them in series.  Also consider how you might detect a welded contact for mandatory replacement.

Comment: To add a schematic to any SE site: 1) Start a question on a site that _has_ a schematic editor.  This includes Electronics, Raspberry Pi, and maybe some others. 2) Draw and insert the schematic as usual. 3) Copy the generated markup into where you actually want it. 4) Discard the original question.

Comment: Actually if you use toggle switches instead of momentaries you don't need the stop buttons or the other set of contacts. Just 12 switches in parallel and a relay. But then you would have to remember to shut the switches off when you are done and you can't turn the pump off from another location.

Comment: **No.  That is not what I'm talking about.**  I refer to a commercial device made for code electrical work, called a latching relay. Google it.

Comment: @WolfHarper I've never actually seen one of those used, nor did I see what you described in a casual google search.  If I understand correctly though, it sounds like a safety hazard to me because a loose or broken wire could make it impossible to turn the pump off remotely.  That's if you're serious about all the "off" buttons being wired in parallel; I thought it was a typo.

Comment: Try http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/357/105A_755-7090.pdf  ... I'm glad for your enthusiasm about safety, but blind overdesign and condescension don't lead to actual safety. I've seen it tried by novices, it ironically leads to unsafe practice.  Ultimately safety of a particular application depends on its failure tree (worst case scenario), and the designer knows that. Leave it to him.

Comment: I agree with AaronD on the safety aspects, the circuit currently in the answer seems to be in more common use also. It has the extra benefit of cutting the power in case of a blackout, preventing the pump starting when power comes back on. Though a water pump might not be particularly dangerous anyway..

Comment: @jpa it might be if it floods your roof space because it overfills the tank -- I wouldn't want a ceiling falling on my head and the pump may be able to shift more water than any overflow pipe can handle.

Comment: Keep in mind he keeps adding information, which keeps changing the risk picture.  If software can overfill a tank all by itself, you've got bigger problems.  That's what risk analysis is all about.  For instance does the indicator show the commanded position, or the actual one?  Three Mile Island had a problem with that. Based on what we know NOW, he needs a float switch that will cutoff the pump definitely before it reaches a problem level.  He may already have one, most people are not idiots.  I would add a second, lower switch to turn the relay off: belt and suspenders.

Comment: Keeps adding information?  Then why haven't I seen...oh, it's in the disorganized comments that SE hides by default!  Hey @rtecxs, could you please edit ALL the relevant details into your question itself so that everyone can see it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For that many locations, I'd strongly consider one of the types of switches intended for home automation applications.  One switch would actually control the pump, and the others would signal that switch to turn on or off.   Some of them offer battery operated remotes that can be used without any permanent wiring, or you can mount a switch in a normal junction box as long as you have a neutral and hot wire available.

Check into Insteon, Lutron, and Z-wave switches.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I'm missing the issue, but it would seem a lot simpler and possibly cheaper to just install a small pressure tank controlled by a single pressure switch to the incoming water line.